# The placement of the "a" in: Those times are commonly considered a much more refined and intellectual period as opposed to

Tags: articles, syntax

"Those times are commonly considered **a** much more refined period as opposed to..."

(1)The above "a" should be moved before "period", right?
(2) Similarly to: "This is long enough a stick"

Tell me please your understanding of these constructions where we have these adverbials of degree (that's what I believe they are).

Edit: Disregard the above blunder (2).
What I meant is this: We have constructions such as "too long a stick" where "a" goes after the modifying phrase. For some reason I thought, now don't, that the uppermost sentence needed a change in the placement of the article". Can you tell me something more about structures where articles are placed in such a seemingly unusual position -- as in "too long a stick".

Comment: You are proposing a construction along the lines of "... much more refined a period than..." to convey a comparison. While this form of comparison does exist, it is relatively rare nowadays. "... a much more refined period than..." is far more common.

Comment: Native speakers never say *This is long enough **a stick***. They might *sometimes* say *This is **a long enough** stick* - but that would nearly always be a "facetious" usage featuring deliberately quirky phrasing. The idiomatic standard here is simply ***This stick is long enough***.

Comment: Would you prefer "This is considered good a book"?

Answer (score 1):

In your original example, which is quite correct, 'much more refined' is an adjective phrase describing the noun 'period'. In most common constructions, when a noun has an article it goes before any adjectives (eg *a car, a big car, a big red car* etc).

Moving the article in your example would not be correct. Nor is your other example of "this is long enough a stick" correct as it stands.

The constructions you are possibly thinking of are either those that use '*so...that*', for example:

- It was so long a stick that it could reach the ceiling.

Or, possibly those that use '*of a*', to indicate that something is a particular type of thing, for example:

- This is long enough of a stick.